# Transport endpoint is not connected

Tags: mount, fuse

FUSE is **constantly**(every 2 - 3 days) giving me this `Transport endpoint is not connected` error on my mount point and the only thing that seems to fix it is rebooting.

I currently have my mount points setup like this, I'm not sure what other details I should add here so let me know if I missed anything..

```
/dev/sdc1 /mnt/hdd2 ext4 defaults 0 0
/dev/sdb1 /mnt/hdd1 ext4 defaults 0 0
mhddfs#/mnt/hdd1,/mnt/hdd2 /data fuse defaults,allow_other 0 0
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a segmentation fault problem which was introduced in 0.1.39. You may check my repository that fixed this one meanwhile: https://github.com/vdudouyt/mhddfs-nosegfault

Answer (score 338):

I have exactly the same problem. I haven't found a solution anywhere, but I have been able to fix it without rebooting by simply unmounting and remounting the mountpoint.

For your system the commands would be:

```
fusermount -uz /data
mount /data
```

The `-z` forces the unmount, which solved the need to reboot for me. You may need to do this as `sudo` depending on your setup. You may encounter the below error if the command does not have the required elevated permissions:

> fusermount: entry for /data not found in /etc/mtab

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, with the current version of `mhddfs`.

Comment: This doesn't exactly fix it but I guess it's the best answer for now.

Comment: I was getting the same error message with SSHFS, and this fixed it too. Thanks.

Comment: Not work for me - fusermount -uz /media/srv2/tickets/
fusermount: entry for /media/srv2/tickets not found in /etc/mtab

Comment: This worked for me after my mount.ntfs (NTFS-3G) got OOM-killed.

Comment: This worked for me, even when "umount -f <>" failed.

Comment: mine was caused by xrdp and i just `unmount xrdp-chansrv`.  did not bother re-mounting as i was not using drives over the link

Comment: This worked for me, after I got the 'transport endpoint' problem when I unmounted an rclone local directory during a file transfer. The man page for `fusermount` is misleading; `-z  lazy unmount` does not sound like it will force anything...

Comment: This should be the answer for the most of us coming here. :-)

Comment: This was a fantastic fix when encfs suddenly failed to access the decrypted mount point.  Much appreciated, saved me from rebooting.

Answer (score 121):

This typically is caused by the mount directory being left mounted due to a crash of your filesystem. Go to the parent directory of the mount point and enter `fusermount -u YOUR_MNT_DIR`.

If this doesn't do the trick, do `sudo umount -l YOUR_MNT_DIR`.

Comment: in my case it was not a crash but a previously failed sshfs mount command and not a fs crash.  Still it had been mounted and neeed unmounting.  This answer worked perfectly

Comment: `sudo umount -l DIR` works for me as @Paul said, mine was due to stopping sshfs while executing.

Answer (score 17):

I get this error from the sshfs command from Fedora 17 linux to debian linux on the Mindstorms EV3 brick over the LAN and through a wireless connection.

Bash command:

```
el@defiant /mnt $ sshfs root@192.168.13.102:/root -p 22 /mnt/ev3
fuse: bad mount point `/mnt/ev3': Transport endpoint is not connected
```

This is remedied with the following command and trying again:

```
fusermount -u /mnt/ev3
```

**These additional sshfs options prevent the above error from concurring:**

```
sudo sshfs -d -o allow_other -o reconnect -o ServerAliveInterval=15 root@myremoteserver.com:/var/lib/redmine/plugins /mnt -p 12345 -C
```

In order to use `allow_other` above, you need to uncomment the last line in `/etc/fuse.conf`:

```
# Set the maximum number of FUSE mounts allowed to non-root users.
# The default is 1000.
#
#mount_max = 1000

# Allow non-root users to specify the 'allow_other' or 'allow_root'
# mount options.
#
user_allow_other
```

Source: http://slopjong.de/2013/04/26/sshfs-transport-endpoint-is-not-connected/

Answer (score 10):

Now this answer is for those lost souls that got here with this problem because they force-unmounted the drive  **but** their hard drive is **NTFS Formatted**. Assuming you have ntfs-3g installed (sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g).

```
sudo ntfs-3g /dev/hdd /mnt/mount_point -o force
```

Where **hdd** is the hard drive in question and the "/mnt/mount_point" directory exists.

**NOTES:**
This fixed the issue on an Ubuntu 18.04 machine using NTFS drives that had their journal files reset through **sudo ntfsfix /dev/hdd** and unmounted by force using **sudo umount -l /mnt/mount_point**

Leaving my answer here in case this fix can aid anyone!

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to mount a usb drive with `/etc/fstab` and you get this error.
The first thing to do is to uninstall usbmount package.
`sudo apt remove usbmount`.
Then if your fstab config is correct, after reboot it should be mounted correctly on boot.
Source:
https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=131484

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I dropped my 64GB camera memory card on the floor. Carefully dusting the card's contacts did not help. Rebooting did not help. Then I put the card back in the camera, reformatted it, and all was well again.

Answer (score -6):

I had this problem when using [X2Go](https://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php). The problem happened in a folder that was shared between the remote computer and my local PC.

Solution: cd out of that folder and in again. That fixed it.